# i would like to loop through this and get each "transactionReference"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, object

```
"responseBody": {
        "content": [{
                "paymentMethod": "ACCOUNT_TRANSFER",
                "createdOn": "2019-10-29T11:02:00.000+0000",
                "amount": 22.00,
                "flagged": false,
                "currencyCode": "NGN",
                "completedOn": "2019-10-29T11:08:11.000+0000",
                "paymentDescription": "Isoken 001",
                "paymentStatus": "EXPIRED",
                "transactionReference": "MNFY|20191029110159|005805",
                "paymentReference": "MNFY|20191029110159|005805",
                "merchantCode": "ZETBBQ5Q7VLB",
                "merchantName": "Lahray LTD "
            },
            {
                "paymentMethod": "ACCOUNT_TRANSFER",
                "createdOn": "2019-10-29T10:45:12.000+0000",
                "amount": 22.00,
                "flagged": false,
                "fee": 0.18,
                "currencyCode": "NGN",
                "completedOn": "2019-10-29T10:49:49.000+0000",
                "paymentDescription": "Isoken 001",
                "paymentStatus": "PAID",
                "transactionReference": "MNFY|20191029104511|005830",
                "paymentReference": "MNFY|20191029104511|005830",
                "merchantCode": "ZETBBQ5Q7VLB",
                "merchantName": "Lahray LTD ",
                "payableAmount": 22.00
            }
        ],
        "last": false,
        "totalElements": 258,
        "totalPages": 129,
        "first": true,
        "numberOfElements": 2,
        "size": 2,
        "number": 0,
        "empty": false
    }
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Where are you stuck? What is your question? Using `javascript`, `jquery` or `php`?

Answer (score -1):

Hello you try to do [Object Iteration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php), check the official documentation's link in PHP for more.

**Clear Point:** let me explain it simply as who I'm see the thing, your output is an object output.. let suppose that object is named "transactionReferences"

You can looping thought this object. Foreach loop would work fine with you in this case.

How it works:

```
foreach ($transactionReferences as $value) {
   echo $obj->property;
}
```

**More approach** using to access your object properties

```
foreach ($transactionReferences as $value){
      echo $value->content;
}
```

Hope this explanation helps

Comment: Where is `$transactionReferences` set? Getting those seems to be OPs real question

Comment: I just anticipated that.. to give him a clear point about what he must do if he's not have.